# how to block requests containing specific http header in chrome extension mv3?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to block requests containing specific HTTP header, for example, when header "Accept-Encoding" contains "zip". How can I achieve it with declarativeNetRequest in chrome extension mv3?

Comment: Please read this first. [chrome.declarativeNetRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/)

Comment: I have read it, and I know it can modify headers, but it does not mention using HTTP headers as conditions.

Comment: There's no way, it's not implemented, https://crbug.com/1141166. Enjoy ManifestV3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way for now, thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom).